# Jogo das 3 portas Java

Tags: java, matriz, random

Tenho que fazer um exercício em Java que consiste em criar uma matriz [3][3] sendo que cada linha seria uma fase do jogo. O usuário deve adivinhar em que porta está o prémio. Para isso preciso fazer um *random* em cada linha atribuindo o valor 1 para a porta com prémio e 0 para as demais, a pergunta é como faço esse *random* linha por linha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe `java.util.Random` possui um método [`nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) que retorna um inteiro no intervalo `[0,n[`, dado um `n` de entrada. Usando `3`, ele retornará um número em `[0,1,2]`. Aí é só atribuir a porta com esse número para `1`, e manter as outras com `0`:

```
Random r = new Random();
// para cada linha
int qual = r.nextInt(3);
linha[qual] = 1;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mgibsonbr, vou tentar aqui.

Comment: @MarcioRezende Eu vi o código que você postou e apagou, você já deve tê-lo resolvido sozinho, mas se não, duas dicas: 1) Coloque o sorteio dentro do loop, não fora (caso contrário, a porta sorteada será a mesma todas as vezes); 2) Você não precisa de um loop interno, pois os arrays de inteiros em Java já vêm inicializados com tudo zero - basta fazer `porta[i][qual] = 1`.

Comment: mgibsonbr, valeu a força. Vi que estava fazendo bobagem, tenho uma professora que não dá aula, passa exercício e nem corrige. Estou aprendendo mais aqui com vocês do que em classe :). Valeu.